# UNP folder found in Program Files

Tags: windows-10

I am using Windows and I suddenly have a new folder called UNP in Program files. I tried to delete that but still it returns after some time. Is that any harm ? Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Don't delete folders in Program Files unless you know what they're for and what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not new but it's been modified recently.

It seems to be related to notifications of  Windows Feature updates, so it has probably been made ready for the May update which was released last week.